# Devise custom validation for a custom field in the registration form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

to add a field to the registration is no problem, but how to generate a validator for this new field.

In my case i add a checkbox and i want to reject the registration if the checkbox is not set checked.

Any hints for me ?

Regards,
Xavael

Comment: what is the type of the field?

Comment: the field is boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have generated you devise logic with a User model and want's to validate that. The in your file user.rb you add something like:

```
validates :name_of_column, acceptance: true, message: 'must be checked'
```

Comment: validates :confirm_terms_and_conditions, acceptance: true, message: 'must be checked'
without the message part it works. But with it i get this error : Unknown validator: 'MessageValidator'

Comment: validates :confirm_terms_and_conditions, acceptance: { accept: ['1', true], message: 'must be accepted' }   this works

Answer (score 0):

Try sth like this:

```
 validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true, message: 'must be abided'
```

Comment: but where to put the validation in ?

Comment: @Xavael in the model has reference with devise